# Run code under WCF vs "regular" code execution, what the difference?

Tags: .net, wcf, sharepoint, runtime

I have peace of code (uses SharePoint Object Model) that runs in two modes:

1. Run from plain console application or from unit test runner. In this case code works.
2. Run in WCF Service. WCF Service is hosted in console application. No special security configurations, everything by default. Execution fails.

What possible differences in execution for this two modes, especially related to security(e.g. contexts, principals)?

SharePoint Object Model is where problem appears, but this is not primary target of question. It is more interesting what differences in general case. If you need more specifics, let me know, I will update question.

Differences so far:

1. Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread (#1 - false, #2 - true), it obviously comes from threadpool

Comment: It would be helpful to post failure details.

Comment: Failure is SharePoint specific and SharePoint never gives error messages that really means what it says. For example in my case, I am adding claims to resource and error message is "The user does not exist or is not unique." This is because claim is really user object in SharePoint. Also error is COMException so I cannot even decompile to see real problem.

Comment: Is the WCF console application running on the SharePoint server? Client object model, or server object model?

Comment: Server Object Model on SharePoint Server. Now I can say even more. If I create full blown Thread from WCF Service, and in this thread I run my code it also works. Wired.

Comment: I probably need remove any mentions of the sharepoint at all from this question.

Answer (score -1):

The Sharepoint objects are COM based under the hood. WCF is multithreaded by default which is incompatible with COM.

Comment: I would point out that you said the exception was COMException which implies that the model is interacting with COM objects at some level.

Comment: I am not sure where is my previous comment. But anyway. There is no incompatibilities between COM and multithreading. As I said in previous comment, ASP.NET is fully multithreaded, but works totally fine with SharePoint COM object model.